# Run Java command line from node.js dokku container

Tags: java, docker, dokku

I have a dokku container running a `node.js` app, my backend needs to use `java8` to run some command lines. I have the following error message from my server:

> [Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c java 
>       /bin/sh: 1: java: not found
>       ]

How can I make `java8` accessible inside my dokku container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your own image based on current one (or modify your current Dockerfile if you already have it) and add java to it. How exactly to add java depends on base image and java which you need. Here the sample for [ubuntu based image and oracle java8](https://github.com/dockerfile/java/blob/master/oracle-java8/Dockerfile)

After that you could [run container](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#run) from that image. You could use your local image or you could [push](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#push) your image to public or private registry.

Here [Dockerfile documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/) and [best practices](https://docs.docker.com/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/) for it creation.

Comment: I followed your advice, I couldn't get my hand over the Dockerfile used by Dokku and tried many things before finding a very ugly working solution. I first run my app using dokku without setting up java, this creates a docker image on my server with node and all the correct dependencies. I then add a dockerfile to my repo referencing my currently running docker image (FROM <docker_image>) and setting up java. I guess there are cleaner ways to do this, this is my first deployment ever so I am a bit lost. I also tried to use the dokku-apt plugin without success.